# Count consistent duplicates in python?

Tags: python

here is the input:

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,1,1]
```

and I want to get the output like:

```
out      = [1,2,3,4,1]
count    = [2,1,1,1,2]
```

This is different from **numpy.unique** function.

here is my code, any better solutions?

```
def unique_count(input):
tmp = None
count = 0
count_list = []
value_list = []
for i in input:
    if i == tmp:
        count += 1
    else:
        if tmp != None:
            count_list.append(count)
            value_list.append(tmp)
        count = 1
        tmp = i
count_list.append(count)
value_list.append(tmp)
return((value_list,count_list))
```

Comment: Quite easy with https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Something like `out, count = zip(*((k,len(list(v))) for k,v in groupby(a)))`

Comment: @yatu: please don't link to the Python 2 doc

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

a = [1,1,2,3,4,1,1]

group_counts = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(a)]

out, count = map(list, zip(*group_counts))

print(out)
print(count)
```

Or all in one line:

```py
out, count = map(list, zip(*((k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(a))))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what's going on inside, you can take a look. Then you can try any library or other shorted/smarter solution. This is also a linear solution by the way.

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,4,1,1]
def customDupCounter(a):
    result = [a[0]]
    counter = [1]
    curr_index = 0
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        if a[i] == a[i-1]:
            counter[curr_index] += 1
        else:
            curr_index += 1
            result.append(a[i])
            counter.append(1)
    return result, counter
result, counter = customDupCounter(arr)
print(result)
print(counter)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1]
uniques = []
count = []

curCount = 0
for i, num in enumerate(a):
    if i == 0 or a[i - 1] != num:
        uniques.append(num)

    if a[i - 1] == num:
        curCount += 1
    else:
        count.append(curCount)
        curCount = 1

count.append(curCount)

print(uniques)
print(count)
```

Here, we go through each number in the code and add it to the uniques list if the previous number in the list was different. We also have a variable to keep track of the count which resets to 1 if the previous number was different.

Comment: this is not the output he wants. he wants to count consecutive numbers